# how to send an object back to the controller with spring

Tags: java, html, spring

I am creating my first spring web app and before i went about things the wrong way i was wanted to ask here first. What i am doing is essentially passing a Java object to a jsp page and displaying the data. The object i'm passing has a list of other objects. I have two buttons, what i want to do is return an item in my object's list depending on the button while also refreshing the page (i assume i have to refresh without using javascript). Anyway, TLDR; how do i use a button to return an object to the controller and refresh the page?

Comment: make a POST request and pass your data

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy sorry i'm still pretty new, what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/) tutorial contains step by step guide which is similar to what you want.

In particular,refer these parts of the tutorial.

```
<form:form method="post" action="save.html" modelAttribute="contactForm">
```

and

> save() method: This method is used to fetch contact data from the form
>   submitted and save it in the static array.

Comment: I'm not doing a form, i just want to return a different object based on which button was clicked. I'd also prefer to not load a different page just refresh the current page with new data

Comment: We are here you show you direction, if you struck.No one can do your job/homework.

Comment: I'm able to pass back strings but when i try to pass back an object or a list it ends up not working